# How to get Strafers on Navox: Ormos, in Story Sector 2?

Tags: creeper-world-3-arc-eternal

How to get Strafers on Navox: Ormos, in Story Sector 2?

I beat the planet that gives me Strafers, but was my issue that I went to Ormos first so the game knows that I shouldn't have strafers and is locking them out, unlike [the Mortar & Cannon-less run](https://youtu.be/nEnBpKMbmTA?t=443)?

And so I guess I have to delete my system.dat for that system to reset its knowledge? Which doesn't seem to work. Is there a way that does?

Answer (score 0):

The equipment shown *before* you send your Command Node to the surface is inaccurate compared to what you *actually* have when you ship out.

So you actually do have Strafers since they show up after shipping out.

Why you lack Bombers from Flick, I'm not sure, but not like it matters. Ormos has no Ore to make Anti-Creeper anyway.